# NEO4J find any nodes that have relationships (direct/indirect) with all nodes in a set

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-ogm

I'm new to neo4j so I'm probably making some kind of basic mistake here:

**This is a subset of my graph:**

[image]

I have 3 kinds of nodes:

- (blue) attribute
- (red) business
- (yellow) promotion

`attributes` can have relationships to `promotions` and `businesses` (`:TAGS`)

This is my best guess cypher query so far.

```
MATCH(a:Attribute)--(b:Business)--(p:Promotion)
WHERE a.name IN ["business", "casual", "happy_hour"]
RETURN a, b, p
UNION
MATCH(a:Attribute)--(p:Promotion)--(b:Business)
WHERE a.name IN ["business", "casual", "happy_hour"]
RETURN a, b, p;
```

This isn't quite what I'm looking, it returns `promotions` related to ***one or more*** `attributes`

I want to only return `promotions` that have relationships to **all** `attributes` in a given set of attributes. How should I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work.

```
// create collection of myTagNodes
WITH ["business", "casual", "happy_hour"] AS myTags
MATCH (myTagNode:TAG) WHERE myTagNode.name IN myTags
WITH COLLECT(myTagNode) AS myTagNodes

// only return promotions for which all 'myTagNodes'are in the 
// (indirectly) connected tags, i.e. through buisnesses or directly
MATCH (p:Promotion)
     WHERE ALL(myTagNode IN myTagNodes 
               WHERE myTagNode IN [(p)<-[*1..2]-(pTagNode:TAG) | pTagNode] 
           )
RETURN p
```

See also https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/syntax/lists/#cypher-list-comprehension and
https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/syntax/lists/#cypher-pattern-comprehension

Comment: Thanks for the help, could you point to some docs re this: `[(p)<-[*1..2]-(pTagNode:TAG) | pTagNode]`

Comment: links to documentation added